# Problem with Stripe PHP - local files not with composer

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to run Stripe from a page in localhost from a Windows Server 2003. The code I have seems to work on Windows Sevrer 2016 as I can use Composer with that system. I have tried using the local files, but nothing seems to happen.

```
<?php

require_once('stripe-php/init.php');

Stripe::setApiKey('***********');

//sanitize post array
$POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$firstName = $POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $POST['lastName'];
$emailAddress = $POST['emailAddress'];
$token = $POST['stripeToken'];
$amount = $POST['amount'] * 100;
$guestID = $POST['guestID'];
$itemsBought = $POST['itemBought'];

//create customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "description" => $firstName . " " . $lastName,
  "email" => $emailAddress,
  "source" => $token
));

//create charge
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => $amount,
  "currency" => "gbp",
  "description" => $itemsBought,
  "customer" => $customer->id
));

echo $charge;

?>
```

I am running PHP 5.4.4, any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "nothing seems to happen"? The PHP file itself won't do anything unless you POST data to it from a frontend web page using Stripe Checkout/Elements. Do you get an error messages, or logs in your Stripe dashboard?

Comment: @karllekko sorry, there is a front end which posts the data and inserts it into $POST. This page definitely works as I can echo out the $POST array when I remove the other Stripe code. When I then add in the Stripe code, it will not echo anything.

Comment: sounds like there's probably an exception that you're not seeing, try adding `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); ` and see if it helps?

Comment: @karllekko nope, still not getting anything... hmmm...

Comment: Maybe try `\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey` instead of `Stripe::setApiKey`. If I use your code it throws a `Class 'Stripe' not found` error, so you should check your server settings to find out why you don't see that error in your logs if it's happening

Comment: @karllekko I have tried this, but with the same result. I have now managed to get composer installed on the system I am working with, so am now using vendor/autoload instead. Don't think it makes much difference though!